# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber') ionic 4 only ios

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic4

I'm currently working on an ionic4 application using Firebase notification and phone verification. And as I searched the same error would be solved for android by adding the SHA-1 key to the firebase console. Now both verification and notification are working well in android, however, while I am trying to use phone verification in iOS it doesn't send the verification code to the number and shows the following errors.

```
    [Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber')
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber')
    error
    View_VerifyNumberPage_Host_0 (VerifyNumberPage_Host.ngfactory.js:4)
    logError (vendor.js:60262)
    (anonymous function)
    handleError (vendor.js:51895)
    run (polyfills.js:2512)
    tick (vendor.js:54249)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:54133:110)
    onInvoke (vendor.js:53422)
    run (polyfills.js:2512)
    next (vendor.js:54133:85)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:49638)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:178400)
    next (vendor.js:178338)
    _next (vendor.js:178284)
    next (vendor.js:178261)
    next (vendor.js:178027)
    emit (vendor.js:49622)
    checkStable (vendor.js:53391)
    onHasTask (vendor.js:53435)
    hasTask (polyfills.js:2805)
    _updateTaskCount (polyfills.js:2825)
    _updateTaskCount (polyfills.js:2653)
    runTask (polyfills.js:2574)
    drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2963)
    promiseReactionJob
[Error] ERROR CONTEXT – DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object, …}
DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object, …}DebugContext_
    error
    View_VerifyNumberPage_Host_0 (VerifyNumberPage_Host.ngfactory.js:4)
    logError (vendor.js:60262)
    (anonymous function)
    handleError (vendor.js:51900)
    run (polyfills.js:2512)
    tick (vendor.js:54249)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:54133:110)
    onInvoke (vendor.js:53422)
    run (polyfills.js:2512)
    next (vendor.js:54133:85)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:49638)
    __tryOrUnsub (vendor.js:178400)
    next (vendor.js:178338)
    _next (vendor.js:178284)
    next (vendor.js:178261)
    next (vendor.js:178027)
    emit (vendor.js:49622)
    checkStable (vendor.js:53391)
    onHasTask (vendor.js:53435)
    hasTask (polyfills.js:2805)
    _updateTaskCount (polyfills.js:2825)
    _updateTaskCount (polyfills.js:2653)
    runTask (polyfills.js:2574)
    drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2963)
    promiseReactionJob
```

Now I'm gonna what I think is needed for debugging.

```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";
import { SingletonService } from "../constants/single-ton.service";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";
import { ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { AlertService } from "../alert/alert.service";
import { StorageService } from '../storage/storage.service';

declare var window;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SmsVerificationService {
  firebaseId:any;
  constructor(
    public http: HTTP,
    public route: Router,
    private modal: ModalController,
    public alertService: AlertService,
    public storageService : StorageService
  ) {
    firebase.initializeApp(SingletonService.firebaseConfig);
  }
  getVerifiedId(number: any, storage) {
    let phone = "+93" + number;

    window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phone,
      60,
      function(credential) {
        let myVerificationID = credential.verificationId;
        // This is STEP 2 — passing verification ID to verify Page
        storage.set("verificationID", myVerificationID);
        storage.set("phoneNumber", phone);
        console.log(
          "The verification id in getverifiedID function ",
          myVerificationID
        );
      },
      error => {
        console.error("error in getVefiried function \n " + error);
      }
    );
  }
  isVerified(code: string, title, phone, storage) {
    let isVerified: boolean;
    storage.get("verificationID").then(val => {
      console.log("The verification id is " + val);
      console.log("the verfication code is " + code);
      let signInCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        val,
        code
      );
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithCredential(signInCredential)
        .then(
          info => {
            console.log("The info of verification is ");
            console.log(info);
            this.firebaseId = info.user.uid;
            this.storageService.set("firebaseId",this.firebaseId);
            console.log(this.firebaseId);

            let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
              state: {
                phone: phone
              }
            };
            console.log("title is ", title);
            if (title === "بازیابی حساب") {
              this.route.navigate(["/reset-password"], navigationExtras);
              console.log("if is correct");
              this.modal.dismiss(null, "cancel");
            } else {
              this.route.navigate(["/create-account"]);
              console.log("else is correct ");
              this.modal.dismiss(null, "cancel");
            }
          },
          error => {
            console.log(" error while verifiying the app " + error);
            this.alertService.presentAlert("کود 6 رقمی که وارد کرده اید درست نمی باشد","لغو");
          }
        );
      console.log("Is user verified " + isVerified);
    });
  }
}
```

[image: The project on firebase console]

Let me know If I need to upload my package.json or config.xml file.
**Any kind of help is appreciated.**

Comment: any hints? thanks :)